# I am passion or I have passion

Tags: difference, nouns

Which is the correct one to use? Or are they both correct?

> I am passion for seeing your getaways' photos.

or

> I have passion for seeing your getaways' photos.

Comment: passion is quite a strong feeling so I wouldn't use it in this kind of context. How about, "I am looking forward to seeing your getaways photos."? If you really wanna use "passion", the correct way would be: "I am passionate about seeing your getaways photos."

Comment: Passion is a noun. Passionate is an adjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I agree with the comment left by @Pochi – *passion* is probably too strong a word to use for wanting to see someone’s photos. We typically reserve *passion* for long-term interests, not short-term events we can do in an afternoon.

So, for example, I might say:

> I have a passion for fishing.

particularly if I’m in my boat nearly every weekend. However, no matter how strong this passion may be, I would never say to my friend:

> I have a passion for fishing with you next weekend.

Rather, I would use Pochi’s wording instead:

> I’m looking forward to fishing with you next weekend.

So, the answer to your question is:

- We generally use *have*, not *am*, as the verb
- We often (though not always) use the indefinite article in such contexts.

[This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+passion+for%2Chave+a+passion+for&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) shows the prevalence of usage with the article.

That said, we **can** use *am* if we use the word *passionate* instead of *passion*:

> I am passionate about fishing.